Magento 2 : Print order pdf's error since upgrade to 2.4.7
I have upgrading to 2.4.7, after that I can no longer print any order pdf's, which is obviously problematic.
Exception log below but I am not technical enough to know how to fix it!

main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to undefined function
Magento\Framework\File\Pdf\ImageResource\tmpfile() in
/home/1125497.cloudwaysapps.com/fxfdjhhsew/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/File/Pdf/ImageResource/ImageFactory.php:69

I am not technical enough to know how to fix this.  Any detailed suggestions would be gratefully appreciated

I have this issue, too. Did you find the solution?

tmpfile was disabled in php check php.ini for disable_functions=tmpfile

Cool ! I bet it's the same solution for @chacha
You can mark it as approved answer if you want !

@AndeeKnits
Hey,
composer update
enter php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flushcode here

Thank You!
